# What does "carbon-based predecessors" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Cyberspace, as it exists now on the online networks, is only a
>   harbinger of the screenless, image-based, computer-generalized worlds
>   of future long-distance communication. More than downloadable
>   photographs and instantaneous chat, future electronic worlds will be
>   entered, reconnoitered, touched, monitored and replayed, in part
>   supplementing their **carbon-based predecessors**. Surreptitiously,
>   almost insidiously, machines integrate themselves in our lives.

Intuitively, I would think it means the previous electronic worlds. But if I adopt this explanation, the *carbon-based* seems to be somewhat weird since it is usually related to creatures. Hence I think maybe its meaning is human beings and predecessors indicates inventors. Am I correct?

A picture of the original passage is available at https://s22.postimg.io/fosdxav8x/e8c6d2798c5fc82_Copy.jpg

Comment: Please include a link to the source where this passage may be found.

Comment: What do you mean "somewhat wired"?

Comment: @AlanCarmack I only have a picture of the passage, It's available at https://s22.postimg.io/fosdxav8x/e8c6d2798c5fc82_Copy.jpg . Sorry for "wired", that's a typo, it should be "weird".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *Carbon-based predecessors* refers to people. You are right, it does not refer to the electronic worlds or to the future.

The paragraph simply suggests that electronics (Silicon-based) will replace people.  The reference to communications being carbon-based is simply referring to face-to-face speech.

The intention is not to refer specifically to the inventors of the electronic systems.

The whole thing is metaphorically stating that the machines are taking over.  You will find other works of literature that use similar phraseology,.

Answer (score -1):

The term *carbon-based* describes only  *predecessors*; it does not apply to *future electronic worlds*.

The noun phrase *their  carbon-based predecessors* is compared  to  *future electronic worlds*, which,   in turn, goes back to *screenless, image-based, computer-generalized worlds of future long-distance communication.*

It does not matter if *future electronic worlds*  are not carbon-based. This passage describes only  *their predecessors* as  carbon-based. The  quality of carbon-based is not being ascribed to *future electronic worlds*.

You can rewrite the passage as

> ...future electronic worlds will be entered, reconnoitered, touched, monitored and replayed, in part supplementing **their predecessors,  which were carbon-based**.

Here again, carbon-based describes only *their predecessors*, not any future world.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused by the usage of "carbon-based". Does it refer to those entities?

Comment: In this passage, **carbon-based** only refers to **the predecessors** of future electronic worlds.

Comment: Maybe I failed to express my confusion properly. Why does the author use "carbon-based" on predecessors? It is unusual to me because it's hard for me to understand why the predecessors, not creatures are "carbon-based" .